# Angular app loads, then freezes in Firefox

Tags: angularjs

There are no errors thrown, and the app works in Chrome.

```
/* app.js */
var app = app || angular.module('app', []);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/look', {templateUrl: 'partials/look.html', controller: 'DataCtrl'});
}]);

/* Controllers */
var app = app || angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.orderProp = 'id';
    $http.get('data/data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

Any hint of what could be going wrong? Please let me know if more data is needed.

Comment: describe freezes. The browser becomes unresponsive?

Comment: Yes, textboxes wouldn't respond. I couldn't scroll the page.

Comment: This resolved "itself". I don't know what I did, but now it doesn't freeze anymore. Sorry for the inconvenience. I'll leave this here should others have a similar problem.

Comment: A problem that "resolved itself" cannot be be of any help to others.

Comment: I agree with you, Stewie, but wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Mine is freezing now too. I've no idea why. I've just added some ng-if directives to some elements, added a $watch on a variable to make updates when it changes, etc, normal stuff...